# Logged in user can see only his own content (Angular+Firebase)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have a file named user.service.ts with a following code (I set firebase authentication here):

```
export class UserService {
uid = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    map((authState) => {
        if (!authState) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return authState.uid;
        }
    })
);
isAdmin: Observable<boolean>= this.uid.pipe(
    switchMap(uid=>{
        if(!uid){
            return observableOf(false);
        } else{
            return this.firebase.object<boolean>('/admin/'+ uid).valueChanges()
        }
    })
);
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) {}

login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}
logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
}
```

I have a file named employee.service.ts, and this is how I insert employees in firebase:

```
insertEmployee(employee) {
this.employeeList.push({
caseId: employee.caseId,
caseName: employee.caseName,
department: employee.department,
startDate: employee.startDate==""?"":this.datePipe.transform(employee.startDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy'),
startTime: employee.startTime,
finishTime: employee.finishTime,
isPermanent: employee.isPermanent,
description: employee.description,
remark: employee.remark,
serviceType: employee.serviceType,
isReplaceable: employee.isReplaceable,
maintainer: employee.maintainer,
contracts: employee.contracts,
dnevnica: employee.dnevnica,
client: employee.client
});
}
```

In the same file, I get employees like:

```
getEmployees(){
this.employeeList=this.firebase.list('employees');
return this.employeeList.snapshotChanges();
}
```

My question is: How I can connect this insert with client id? To be more concrete, I want to make every user see only his content, how can I do that?

Comment: Add a client id column

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you mean, but I would be good if it's that simple:)

Comment: Add a client id column to your tables and select only rows for the current client id.

Comment: Tried to do that, but without success. Thank you, anyways.